# How do I map this list of objects to an expandable listview?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, expandablelistview

I'm creating objects from json with jackson and I want to show those objects in an 
`expandableListView`.

The json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pete",
    "profile_img": "img001",
    "relations": {
      "is_working_with": [],
      "is_in_course_with": [
        {
          "profile_img": "img002",
          "name": "Jack"
        }
      ],
      "is_friends_with": [
        {
          "profile_img": "img003",
          "name": "Stacey"
        },
        {
          "profile_img": "img002",
          "name": "Jack"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "profile_img": "img002",
    "relations": {
      "is_working_with": [{
        "profile_img": "img003",
        "name": "Stacey"
      }],
      "is_in_course_with": [
        {
          "profile_img": "img001",
          "name": "Pete"
        }
      ],
      "is_friends_with": [
        {
          "profile_img": "img003",
          "name": "Stacey"
        },
        {
          "profile_img": "img001",
          "name": "Pete"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And my java classes are:

```
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("profile_img")
    String profileImg;
    @JsonProperty("relations")
    Relations relations;

    //Constructors
    //Setter, Getter
}
public class Relations {
    @JsonProperty("is_working_with")
    List<IsWorkingWith> isWorkingWith;
    @JsonProperty("is_friends_with")
    List<IsFriendsWith> isFriendsWith;
    @JsonProperty("is_in_course_with")
    List<IsInCourseWith> isInCourseWith;

    //Constructors
    //Setter, Getter
}
public class IsWorkingWith {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("profile_img")
    String profileImg;
}
public class IsFriendsWith {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("profile_img")
    String profileImg;
}
public class IsInCourseWith {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("profile_img")
    String profileImg;
}
```

I was trying to extend `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and I got it working for the group views, but how do I specify which attribute of my `Student` object is representing the child items in the listview.

Basically I want it looking like this:

[image: list mockup]

How should I generate the items in the child view?

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you have illustrated your `ExpandableListView`, the children are the members of the Relations class.  You have an extra dimension in that each member in the Relations class has its own list.

First, let's fix your class definitions:

```
public class Relations {
    @JsonProperty("is_working_with")
    List<Person> isWorkingWith;
    @JsonProperty("is_friends_with")
    List<Person> isFriendsWith;
    @JsonProperty("is_in_course_with")
    List<Person> isInCourseWith;
}

public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("profile_img")
    String profileImg;
}
```

If each relationship has its own properties, i.e. person in-course-with has a property for the course they share, hopefully your JSON annotations can deal with a separate Person subclass.

So just for example let's take `getChildrenCount()`

```
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 3; // because every student has three types of relations
    }
```

Now you come to the more complex part.  You have a single child that itself has a list. So the child view has to handle a varying amount of Persons.  There are different options for this, but if I had to pick I would make the child view a horizontal RecyclerView.

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        // first let's handle the model stuff
        Student student = (Student) getGroup(groupPosition);  // would need to be implemented
        List<Person> persons;
        switch (childPosition) {
        case 0:
            persons = student.isWorkingWith;
            break;
        case 1:
            persons = student.isFriendsWith;
            break;
        case 2:
            persons = student.isInCourseWith;
            break;
        }

        // now set up the view/adapter
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        PersonAdapter adapter;   // you would need to write this
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.child, parent, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            view.setTag("recyclerview", recyclerView);
            adapter = new PersonAdapter(parent.getContext()); // no data yet
            view.setTag("adapter", adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(parent.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.getTag("recyclerview");
            adapter = (PersonAdapter) view.getTag("adapter");
        }

        adapter.setData(persons); // this method needs to call notifyDataSetChanged()

        return view;
    }
```

So you end up with nested adapter-based views.

Instead of `RecyclerView`, you could add/remove your Person views dynamically (not recommended), or you could inflate a horizontal `LinearLayout` that had a dozen or so Person views then hide the views you don't end up using.  But the `RecyclerView` approach is a little more straightforward.

Anyway, hopefully that's enough to get you started.